# Threads synchronization in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to make a project as follows:
I'll have 10 threads, each controlling a column of 10 rectangular box.(10 columns of 10 boxes each) And at every 3s or so, I need 2 of them to change colour(i.e. red), such that at any point of time, there should be 2 red columns of 10 red boxes out of 10.

The current code I have for the column of boxes:

```
void* thread_func_1() {
      while (1) {
           if (randomNo1 == 1 || randomNo2 == 1) {
               sema_wait(&sem) ;
               drawRedBoxes();
               sleep(3000);
               drawBlueBoxes();
               sema_post(&sem);
               randomize(); // random 2 more numbers 
           }else{
               drawBlueBoxes();
          }      
}

void randomize(){
    do{
        randomNo1 = 1 + rand()/ (RAND_MAX/(10) + 1);
        randomNo2 = 1 + rand()/ (RAND_MAX/(10) + 1);
    } while (randomNo1 == randomNo2);
}
```

Edit: All the 10 threads are of similar code. The drawBoxes function draws the 10 rectangular boxes in the column.

Not the exact code but it is something like this. Ideally I would want the 2 new red columns to appear together(or at least a very very short time delay between them), but I realised after awhile, it is really obvious that 1 red colum appear some time after another. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This question is not very clear. If the semaphore is protecting the `draw*()` functions, why are you holding the semaphore during the `sleep()`?

Comment: The counting semaphore is initialised to 2. And my intention is to have the 2 boxes stay red for 3s before changing back to the original color and releasing the semaphore.

Comment: Well, I suspect a `barrier` is closer to what you need than a `semaphore`.

Comment: Your question is too hypothetical.  Do you have actual code -- in the form of a [mcve] -- that you can present?  Also, are you using the words "brick" and "bar" interchangeably, or does your usage reflect additional behavioral requirements that you did not mention?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes I was using them interchangeably and I've edited it so it's clearer hopefully.

Comment: Well, if this is your actual code, you have race conditions on non-synchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to `randomNo1` and `randomNo2`. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You also have a thread function with the wrong signature (it should accept one argument of type `void *`), and at thread start you get undefined behavior by inducing that function to be called with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Furthermore, if all your thread functions look like that (i.e. they each call `randomize()`) then even *with* proper synchronization of access to the globals, your threads still wouldn't get a consistent view of them.

Comment: Like so many programmers, you have attempted to state your design by coding it.  Try stating the problem without coding, then code it.  It appears you want to have 10 processes, all of which fire their execution loop every 3s.  They share a pair of variables that tell which ones are red, the rest are blue.  There are surely a few different elegant ways of solving the problem.

Comment: @CarlH hmmm can I have a hint of one way? My processes needs to execute not every 3s but a lot shorter to do some calculations. However when it is red I would want it to stay red for 3s. Therefore the sleep function.

Comment: @Bolo - Ahh, more information!  My point is just reinforced, as is that of other commenters to the effect that your question is hypothetical and not clear.  I wouldn't want to do you the injustice of thinking this out for you and rob you of the satisfaction of solving the problem - draw pictures, diagrams, anything but code to represent your problem in a logical way (UML, sequence diagrams?).  I'm really answering your question, "How can I solve this problem?"  Take it by the horns, don't be afraid of what you think you don't know.  It isn't as difficult as you may think.